# Decipher excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I tried posting this on an Excel forum but their form validation thought I was trying to post a link or image and rejected my post, so I'm trying here.

I need help deciphering this formula. It's trying to calculate a value from several tables in the workbook. I can identify the tables but need help knowing exactly what it's doing with all the colons and things.

```
=IFERROR([@[fee_amount]]*SUMIFS(Invoices!I:I,Invoices!A:A,[@MerchantKey])/SUMIFS(Invoices!F:F,Invoices!A:A,[@MerchantKey]),0)
```

I'm using Excel 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is embedded in an IFERROR function.

```
=IFERROR([if this function is good returns its value], 0)
```

The embedded formula is written for a table which has columns *fee_amount* and *MerchantKey*. There also is a worksheet by the name of *Invoices* in the workbook.
The formula calculates

```
=[Fee_amount] * [SUMIFS(1)] / [SUMIFS(2)]
```

SUMIFS(1) = `SUMIFS(Invoices!I:I,Invoices!A:A,[@MerchantKey])`

SUMIFS(2) = `SUMIFS(Invoices!F:F,Invoices!A:A,[@MerchantKey])`

Of course, each SUMIFS() function has the parameters [SumRange], [Criteria Range] and [Criterium]. If you have access to both the table and the worksheet *Invoices* you can run the functions separately to get their results.